# laravel get Illegal string offset error on getting jsonObject value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in this result of

```
{#457 ▼
  +"id": 14
  +"amount": "110092"
  +"discount": 0
  +"images": "{"images":{"original":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/1513070310.jpeg","300":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1513070310.jpeg","600":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/600_1513070310.jpeg","900":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/900_1513070310.jpeg"},"thumbnail":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1513070310.jpeg"} ◀"
  +"created_at": "2017-12-28 17:48:48"
  +"updated_at": "2017-12-28 19:24:18"
}
```

query, i'm trying to get `thumbnail` from images column which `images` is `JsonObject`, but i get this error:

```
"Illegal string offset 'thumbnail'"
```

my code:

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('payments as s')
    ->join('products as p', 's.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->select('p.*', 's.*',\DB::raw('s.ordering_count * s.price as cost'))
    ->whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)
    ->first();

dd($userShoppings->images['thumbnail']);
```

or

```
dd($userShoppings->images['images']['thumbnail']);
```

error:

```
"Illegal string offset 'images'"
```

my models:

```
class Shopping extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $casts=[
        'images'=>'array'
    ];
}

class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $casts=[
        'images'=>'array'
    ];
}
```

Comment: what does var_dump($userShoppings->images) output?

Comment: "images" looks like a string contain a json_encoded value to me. Do you get the results you need when you do json_decode($userShoppings->images['images']) ?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz this is output: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alachiqServer/app/Http/Controllers/UserShoppingsCardController.php:25:string '{"images":{"original":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/1513070310.jpeg","300":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1513070310.jpeg","600":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/600_1513070310.jpeg","900":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/900_1513070310.jpeg"},"thumbnail":"\/uploads\/post_images\/2017\/300_1513070310.jpeg"}' (length=309)`

Comment: @Jason i get error too

Comment: as i suposed, its a string. you need to convert `$userShoppings->images` to a json or to an array to be able to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `$userShoppings->images` to a json or to an array to be able to use it